# Encrypting and Resetting Surface Pro Tablets

Tags: encryption, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Is it more secure to wipe a Surface Pro Tablet by first applying [BitLocker Encryption](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfhardware/how-to-enable-bitlocker-on-the-surfacepro-windows/2398b22c-3670-44e5-a23e-d73ade4cec87) drive,  logging into the device and cleaning the tablet using ["Fully Clean The Drive"](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/restore-refresh-or-reset-surface-pro) option as defined under the "Reset from within Windows" built-in Surface Pro, then discarding the key securely AS COMPARED TO  just using the "Fully Clean the Drive"?

PS: I just feel like the former is like filling the drive with random numbers (via encryption) then filling it with one pass of a character (via cleaning). The encryption key can then be discarded by saving to a small-storage USB and destroying/multi-pass wiping the USB.

Thanks,

John